# Which is better in performance: a dynamic array determined at run-time vs a class structure in VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, class

I have created a spreadsheet userform that allows users to input information, do surface level data verification, and other things. The problem that I run into is because part of it involves adding all items involved in their submission (the input this is used for could be related to one or more items, sometimes in the higher 30's) I had to create an array and have the array write to the new sheet. This is terribly slow.

I've been learning about classes and thinking that they may be able to provide a sufficient alternative to an array since each item has the exact same information needed. (QTY, UOM, Type, etc) I was thinking of doing 2 classes, one where I have the member class for the item and another where it's the collection and it composes the members objects.

My question is if the performance of doing this would be better than using an array. Are arrays generally the better way of handling collections of data that need to be inputted and outputted to a sheet?

Comment: If you're working with an array of 30-40 items and writing to the sheet is terribly slow, something is very wrong - that should be instantaneous. The choice of a class or an array in this case is only going to be an implementation decision.

Comment: Looping through the array one element at a time and writing that to a cell in the workbook will be slow (for some values of slow). Writing the entire array to a range in one statement should be quite speedy.

Comment: Impossible to answer, but I can assure you that well-written object-oriented VBA code has absolutely no inherent performance problems. If your code works but you need help refactoring it towards a more object-oriented approach, or identifying & fixing performance issues, consider posting it on [codereview.se].

Comment: I think that array would be the most quick solution. Even VBA-Collection uses probably an array internally. But array is fixed size structure, to add new elements to it, new array needs to be created. Class is not relevant to performance, class can be done in a bad way, so performance will be bad or it can be done in a good way. So if you want to do it in object oriented way, use classes and VBA-Collection, if you do it well then the performance of VBA-Collection will be ok, I hope :).